# How Wordpress serves efficiently

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

As per my knowledge I know that PHP file can not serve two clients at same time, so in Wordpress index.php will be the file handling all requests, so how it is all the way efficient and faster? is there any logical clustering? or any programming techniques in PHP that Wordpress follows? I have a website built on index.php where all requests comes to index.php and seems it lags in performance for fewer requests, dont know how it is going well for Wordpress or to some other CMS?

Comment: `As per my knowledge I know that PHP file can not serve two clients at same time` - really? Why? Are you connecting to index.php or a named virtual host served by Apache/Nginx/[insert server] which then in turn invokes a script in thread or process, which comes from a pool of threads/processes?

Comment: @n.b : May be Im not well stuffed, but Ive tested in Apache server under shared hosting, and it is serving only one request once, the other request is kept on hold untill it serves the first.

Comment: It's not up to PHP to determine how requests are served. PHP scripts assume everything is one request. The server creates threads or processes and distributes the work / executes it in parallel. Now, a bunch of threads can share a single resource, such as some file. The thread / process that acquired the lock has the right to do something to it, while others are in stacked and wait until the lock is released. Without knowing what's happening with your script (no code) - then we can't determine if there's a lock in place. Also, you didn't say how you tested nor what Apache config is.

Comment: my script is too simple<?php

sleep(10);

?>, I called this file from one browser as 1:20:20, then from another browser at 1:20:25, then first resuest will comes to end by 1:20:30, if it does multi threading then the second one should complete by 1:20:35, but not so, it completed by 1:20:40 which means it was idle for 15 second, the extra 5 is waiting time/in ques time while it serves for first request is my guess, does my server lag in it?

Comment: Have you tried to do the same from two different IPs? Your Apache could be set up to use pipelining. Without seeing what the config of Apache is - there's no answer to your question. But what's for sure is that PHP has nothing to do with it.

Comment: then where the multi threading comes in PHP? is the same happens to Wordpress? cant we make it to serve two or more at same time? as java/nodejs does?

Comment: You are very confused, PHP doesn't have multithreading capabilities unless it's complied with Thread extension. But that has nothing to do with what you're asking. It's your server that distributes requests. Your index.php gets one request, **all the time**. It never gets two requests. Apache gets N requests at the same time. And it creates threads. Each thread that Apache created invokes your index.php. PHP has **nothing to do with threading here**. Node has nothing to do with threading either, it's a single-thread event-loop based server.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in limit such as "one client per file". You can customize your limits on your webserver and/or your fastCGI pool if you're using one. It will be more accurate to think in terms of "one php thread per request", but even that could be misleading depending on your scenario.

Wordpress's index.php is just a router that in turn picks a theme template and renders it replacing each variable according to the request. No magic there, just basic templating logic.

You index.php lag might be caused by several reasons, including but not limited to:

- You are referencing external js script in the header, which will
  temporarily block page rendering.
- You are trying to establish an early DB connection to a slow or high latency DB server
- You are making heavy SQL queries on each request
- You are not caching sections of the page that are subject to little or no modification from one request to the next
- You are using file based sessions on a slow storage machine
- You are not using an opcode cache AND you're doing an expensive PHP calculation on each request.
- You have a poorly tuned webserver that allocates too much resources for each request, even for static assets.